# How can I get the plain text from the render method from React component or convert a JSX.Element to string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the plain text of a render method **without rendering it into DOM**:

```
class Test from React.Component {

    getPlainText = () => {
        const plainText = /* some method */(this.renderParagraph())
        console.log(plainText) // output in console: <p>I'm text from props of Text component!</p>
    }

    renderParagraph () {
       return <p>{this.props.text}</p>
    }

    render () {
        return <button onClick={this.getPlainText}>click me will print {this.props.text} in console</button>
    }
}
```

I didn't find a possible React or ReactDom API to accomplish this requirement.

Comment: it's actually unclear what you want to do with that text

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code.

Comment: @kg2152 as example shows, I need to log out the stringify html. More accurately, we can feed these text to a keywords parsers, table to excel converter, html structure displayer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that ReactDOMServer.renderToString provides this feature.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

class Test from React.Component {

    getPlainText = () => {
        const plainText = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(this.renderParagraph())
        console.log(plainText) // output in console: <p>I'm text from props of Text component!</p>
    }

    renderParagraph () {
       return <p>{this.props.text}</p>
    }

    render () {
        return <button onClick={this.getPlainText}>click me will print {this.props.text} in console</button>
    }
}
```

Comment: will not work for deep-structured components